# How can I craft XOR Using mod 2 addition in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I read that XOR is equivalent to mod 2 addition. My assumption though is that this is at the bit level. Meaning, 5 XOR 10 is not equal to (5 + 10) mod 2, because that would be 1 which is incorrect. Thus, I've written the following function:

```
unsigned char XOR_BIT(unsigned char A, unsigned char B)
{
    unsigned char x;
    unsigned char y;
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned char o;
    unsigned char output = 0;
    for(c = 0; c < 8; c++)
    {
        printf("=========Round %u=============\n", c);
        x = (A & (1 << c));
        printf("x: %u\n", x);
        y = (B & (1 << c));
        printf("y: %u\n", y);
        o = (x + y) % 2;
        printf("o: %u\n", o);
        output |= (o << c);
        printf("output: %u\n", output);
    }
    return output;
}
```

However, this outputs the following:

```
=========Round 0=============
x: 1
y: 0
o: 1
output: 1
=========Round 1=============
x: 0
y: 2
o: 0
output: 1
=========Round 2=============
x: 4
y: 0
o: 0
output: 1
=========Round 3=============
x: 0
y: 8
o: 0
output: 1
=========Round 4=============
x: 0
y: 0
o: 0
output: 1
=========Round 5=============
x: 0
y: 0
o: 0
output: 1
=========Round 6=============
x: 0
y: 0
o: 0
output: 1
=========Round 7=============
x: 0
y: 0
o: 0
output: 1
MyXOR: 1
Standard XOR: 15
```

I suspect that I am either misunderstanding the bitwise operations required, or I have a code bug but I don't quite have the necessary knowledge in this domain to determine the problem.

The intended behavior of this function is:

1. Grab each byte 1 bit at a time
2. Perform mod 2 addition on each pair of bits
3. Store each result bit in the output
4. Return the output bits as 1 byte

Comment: regarding: `(5 + 10) mod 2,`  There are only two possible results of a `mod 2` they are 0 and 1.  For the whole statement the result is 1.    Definition of 'mod': *Modulo ('%') (often referred as modulus operator) is an arithmetic operator in all programming languages (C, C++, Python etc etc), that finds the remainder when two numbers are divided. Example - 10%4 gives 2, as the remainder when 10 is divided by 4 is 2.*

Comment: the 'exclusive or' operation in C is implemented via the `^` operator.  I.E  A = B^C;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that XOR is equivalent to mod 2 addition. My assumption though
>   is that this is at the bit level. Meaning, 5 XOR 10 is not equal to (5
>   + 10) mod 2, because that would be 5 which is incorrect.

(5 + 10) mod 2 is 1, not 5, but this also is not the same result as the bitwise xor.  You have inferred more or less correctly that the assertion applies to individual bits, but your code suggests that you may not have fully understood that.

Bitwise XOR is fully equivalent to mod 2 addition *in the cyclic group of order 2*, for which mod 2 addition is the ordinary addition operator.  This group has only two elements, conventionally labeled 0 and 1.  Modulo 2 addition is not naturally defined on groups that are not homomorphous to that, though it can be extended in a straightforward way.  Coincidentally, bitwise AND is equivalent to multiplication over the elements of this group.

Consider that the result of a modulo 2 addition is always either 0 or 1, depending on whether the addends have the same or different parity, respectively, and consider that the expression `1 << c` has odd parity if and only if `c` is zero, so that expressions of the form `A & (1 << c)` can have odd parity only when `c` is zero (but the actual parity depends also on `A`).  This should show you why your program is not working as you expect.

You need to map your `x` and `y` to 0 and 1 in order to perform your computation.  There are several ways to do this.  The most obvious way is to perform bitwise shifts, such as another answer already describes.  For your particular purposes, you can also use double logical negation, which in some ways is even more natural. And because of the symmetry of the problem, you can even simplify that to single negation:

```
    x = !(A & (1 << c));
    y = !(B & (1 << c));
    o = (x + y) % 2;
    output |= (o << c);
```

Comment: This answer was very insightful. I am having a difficult time understanding 1 part: " consider that the expression 1 << c has odd parity if and only if c is zero, so that expressions of the form A & (1 << c) can have odd parity only when c is zero (but the actual parity depends also on A)." Say c is 5 and A is 0b10101010, wouldnt A & (1 << 5) be 0b10101010 & 0b00100000 give us 0b00100000 which would be an odd parity since there is 1 bit set?

Comment: @the_endian, I mean "parity" in the conventional sense of the overall number being even *vs* odd.  That's a function of the least-significant bit alone, or more generally, in any even-radix representation, it's a function of the units digit alone.

Comment: Oh I get it now, since the least significant bit always determines odd or even and since we're always ANDing with a 0 there, unless `c = 0`, we will always be ANDing with 0 thus always clearing the bit, always making the number even. Thanks!

Comment: question - is the cyclic group of order 2 a finite field?

Comment: @the_endian, technically, no, the cyclic group of order 2 is a *group*, meaning, among other things, that it has only one operation, whereas a field has two.  But there is a finite field of order 2, and the finite group of order 2 is embedded in that field.

Answer (score 3):

You're adding shifted values before doing the modulo (`x` and `y` should be either 0 or 1 before the mod).  You should be extracting the bits with

```
x = (A >> c) & 1;
y = (B >> c) & 1;
```

Then you add them, do the modulo, and store the bit into `output` like you already are doing.